# List of users in a JIRA Project

Tags: sql, jira

Can someone please help me with a SQL to retrieve users associated to a JIRA project?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ROLETYPEPARAMETER AS USERNAME, R.NAME AS ROLENAME, P.PKEY || ' - ' || P.PNAME AS PROJECTNAME
FROM PROJECTROLEACTOR A
INNER JOIN PROJECTROLE R ON A.PROJECTROLEID = R.ID
INNER JOIN PROJECT P ON A.PID = P.ID
ORDER BY 3, 1, 2;
```

or to just aggregate the users per project:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PKEY, LISTAGG(A.ROLETYPEPARAMETER, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY A.ROLETYPEPARAMETER ASC) OVER(PARTITION BY P.PKEY) AS USERNAMES
FROM PROJECTROLEACTOR A
INNER JOIN PROJECTROLE R ON A.PROJECTROLEID = R.ID
INNER JOIN PROJECT P ON A.PID = P.ID
GROUP BY P.PKEY, A.ROLETYPEPARAMETER;;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jira 6, the correct MySQL syntax is:

```
SELECT 
    A.ROLETYPEPARAMETER AS USERNAME, 
    R.NAME AS ROLENAME, CONCAT(P.pkey, ' - ', P.pname) AS PROJECTNAME
FROM projectroleactor A
INNER JOIN projectrole R ON A.PROJECTROLEID = R.ID
INNER JOIN project P ON A.PID = P.ID
ORDER BY 3, 1, 2
```

NOTE: field names are case-sensitive